# MDPF library generate blank page .. no error even i set debug mode

Tags: php, mpdf

i am using **[mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php)** library, it works perfect individuall in an folder on server, but if i include mpdf library in my application, then it output a blank page. if i see the HTML via firebug then display

```
<html>
       <head></head>
       <body></body>
</html>
```

below is my page code

```
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);    
//include files and mpdf library

$id=(int)$_GET['id'];
//some mysql query and and

$html = "<div id=\"print_target_box\" style=\"display:block;\">";
// some php mysql manipulations
$html .="<b>..</b>
<strong>...</strong><br/>";
// many div and block concatenate by  $html.="";

$html .="</div>";  
$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

---

```
echo phpinfo();
```

returns under **zlib** section

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value
```

and so on...

i also read this link

http://mpdf.bpm1.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one image `` `go.gif `` was  missing on server and this  does not displaying error 
bcoz **error_reporting** was set to `0` in below included  php page..

If you edit file **mpdf.php** and find the line with that error message in it:

```
if (!$im) { return $this->_imageError($file, $firsttime, 
    'Error parsing image file - image type not recognised,
      and not supported by GD imagecreate'); }
```

change this to:

```
if (!$im) { echo $data; exit; }
```

it may show what is going wrong.

reference:
http://mpdf.bpm1.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=235

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was [missing mbregex](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=121). Line that generates the error is @command, which is just fabulous for debugging unknown stuff.